# как отправить ArrayList (несколько строк одним запросом) в SQL через библиотеку jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Структура таблицы в БД это: id (автоинкремент), first_name, last_name.

Есть ArrayList<>() структура которого (String, String) ... и т.д.

Размер arrayList около ~200-300 объектов.

Как отправить весь arrayList одним запросом?

Для работы с MySQL использую библиотеку [jOOQ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ)

Пример:

```
Result<Record> result = ConnectSql.create
                .insertInto(AUTHOR)
                .columns(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
                .values("Вася","Петров")
                .fetch();
```

как передать весь ArrayList в **.values()** ?

Я мог бы передать таким вот образом:

```
  Result<Record> result = ConnectSql.create
                    .insertInto(AUTHOR)
                    .columns(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
                    .values("Вася","Петров")
                    .values("Сергей","Петров")
                    .values("Иван","Иванов")
                    .values("Вася","Пупкин")
                    .values("Сергей","Сергеев")
                    .fetch();
```

но как заполнить всё это дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```java
List<Fio> people = ....;
BatchBindStep batch = dslContext.batch(
            dslContext.insertInto(
                AUTHOR
            ).columns(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME).values(null ,null)
        )
people.forEach((it) -> {
    batch.bind(it.getFirstName(), it.getLastName()) ;
});
batch.execute();
```